# Action bar tabs fill width

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I'm implementing android tabs in the actionbar but seems when displaying the screen on tablet i have a weird issue.
The tabs look like this:
[image]

Does anyone knows a fix or a workaround so the tabs can fill the width of the actionbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple setting works for me:

```
getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```